# Bug in installing Supplychainpy library

Tags: python-3.x

let me know why am getting the below error while installing supplychainpy in ananconda prompt.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\users\a02450\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\a02450\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o7xij43g\supplychainpy\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\a02450\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o7xij43g\supplychainpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\a02450\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5yuhrl0x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Am using windows 10 OS

pip install supplychainpy

Comment: visual studio c++ is required.

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.615]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jainil>pip install supplychainpy
Collecting supplychainpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/cd/b876f8a308a0bc8154eab1ef43422bcc554fd63de124cc57d7ac5ce9ca5f/supplychainpy-0.0.5.tar.gz (4.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.7MB 440kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.29.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.2.11)
Collecting flask-restful (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/44/6e490150ee443ca81d5f88b61bb4bbb133d44d75b0b716ebe92489508da4/Flask_RESTful-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flask-restless (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/ad/14eee74ef110f2bd8641de98675037f037dd06d614f7c435671be66a55c7/Flask-Restless-0.17.0.tar.gz (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.0MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: flask-script in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-sqlalchemy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.3.2)
Collecting flask-uploads (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/a8/2c8e9ec04267d94b7852a374cebeb9a32d60f8cba83818af960e64fafbec/Flask-Uploads-0.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: textblob in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Simplejson in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (3.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->supplychainpy) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->supplychainpy) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask-restful->supplychainpy) (1.12.0)
Collecting aniso8601>=0.82 (from flask-restful->supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/a4/b4fcadbdab46c2ec2d2f6f8b4ab3f64fd0040789ac7f065eba82119cd602/aniso8601-7.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 987kB/s
Collecting mimerender>=0.5.2 (from flask-restless->supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/93/04da69a3a9adae4aae66cf9884f09d82e318018673ba9193a593db01e0ee/mimerender-0.6.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textblob->supplychainpy) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask->supplychainpy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python_mimeparse>=0.1.4 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mimerender>=0.5.2->flask-restless->supplychainpy) (1.6.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: supplychainpy, flask-restless, flask-uploads, mimerender
  Building wheel for supplychainpy (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\16\0b\1b\7e355137bf778b44576a79445ef26424e77854db11e0a6a85a
  Building wheel for flask-restless (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\44\cb\de\b24c9484e9182924860fde31b146e882d90461c3b7aa097243
  Building wheel for flask-uploads (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\af\41\f6\0c357a43a5680e7690ce50337ab7fe9304795910ac10e15ce6
  Building wheel for mimerender (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\55\cb\6c\0b5d39bb361ee92dabc59c8ef4bed48ae2928b53527ccaba90
Successfully built supplychainpy flask-restless flask-uploads mimerender
Installing collected packages: aniso8601, flask-restful, mimerender, flask-restless, flask-uploads, supplychainpy
Successfully installed aniso8601-7.0.0 flask-restful-0.3.7 flask-restless-0.17.0 flask-uploads-0.2.1 mimerender-0.6.0 supplychainpy-0.0.5Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.615]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jainil>pip install supplychainpy
Collecting supplychainpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/cd/b876f8a308a0bc8154eab1ef43422bcc554fd63de124cc57d7ac5ce9ca5f/supplychainpy-0.0.5.tar.gz (4.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.7MB 440kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.29.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (1.2.11)
Collecting flask-restful (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/44/6e490150ee443ca81d5f88b61bb4bbb133d44d75b0b716ebe92489508da4/Flask_RESTful-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flask-restless (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/ad/14eee74ef110f2bd8641de98675037f037dd06d614f7c435671be66a55c7/Flask-Restless-0.17.0.tar.gz (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.0MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: flask-script in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-sqlalchemy in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.3.2)
Collecting flask-uploads (from supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/a8/2c8e9ec04267d94b7852a374cebeb9a32d60f8cba83818af960e64fafbec/Flask-Uploads-0.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: textblob in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (0.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Simplejson in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (3.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from supplychainpy) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask->supplychainpy) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->supplychainpy) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas->supplychainpy) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask-restful->supplychainpy) (1.12.0)
Collecting aniso8601>=0.82 (from flask-restful->supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/a4/b4fcadbdab46c2ec2d2f6f8b4ab3f64fd0040789ac7f065eba82119cd602/aniso8601-7.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 987kB/s
Collecting mimerender>=0.5.2 (from flask-restless->supplychainpy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/93/04da69a3a9adae4aae66cf9884f09d82e318018673ba9193a593db01e0ee/mimerender-0.6.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textblob->supplychainpy) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask->supplychainpy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python_mimeparse>=0.1.4 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mimerender>=0.5.2->flask-restless->supplychainpy) (1.6.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: supplychainpy, flask-restless, flask-uploads, mimerender
  Building wheel for supplychainpy (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\16\0b\1b\7e355137bf778b44576a79445ef26424e77854db11e0a6a85a
  Building wheel for flask-restless (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\44\cb\de\b24c9484e9182924860fde31b146e882d90461c3b7aa097243
  Building wheel for flask-uploads (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\af\41\f6\0c357a43a5680e7690ce50337ab7fe9304795910ac10e15ce6
  Building wheel for mimerender (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\55\cb\6c\0b5d39bb361ee92dabc59c8ef4bed48ae2928b53527ccaba90
Successfully built supplychainpy flask-restless flask-uploads mimerender
Installing collected packages: aniso8601, flask-restful, mimerender, flask-restless, flask-uploads, supplychainpy
Successfully installed aniso8601-7.0.0 flask-restful-0.3.7 flask-restless-0.17.0 flask-uploads-0.2.1 mimerender-0.6.0 supplychainpy-0.0.5
```

WORKING FINE FOR ME, you can check.

Comment: ERROR: Failed building wheel for supplychainpy

Comment: if i can't reproduce your error, i can't solve it. sorry friend, atleast i have tried installing and shared that, it worked fine in my winidows 10 machine. if you want i can share my package list

Comment: Thanks and please share the package list